# Deep comparing each element in an array

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following 3 files,

A.java:

```
class A {

    private float b;    

    public A(float b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public float getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "A(b = " + b + ")";    
    }

}
```

C.java:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class C {

    private A[] d;
    private int i = 0;

    public C() {
        d = new A[5];
    }

    public void addB(A b) {
        d[i++] = b;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "C(b = " + Arrays.toString(d) + ")";    
    }

    public void duplicate() {
        A temp[] = Arrays.copyOf(d, d.length);
        for (int cur = 0; cur < d.length; cur++) {
            if (d[cur] == null) continue;
            float currB = d[cur].getB();
            for (int nxt = cur + 1; nxt < d.length; nxt++) {
                if(d[nxt] == null) continue;
                if(currB == d[nxt].getB()) {
                    temp[i++] = new A(currB * 0.5f);
                }
            }
        }
        d = temp;
    }
}
```

D.java:

```
class D {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C();
        c.addB(new A(3));
        c.addB(new A(5));
        c.addB(new A(3));
        System.out.println(c.toString()); // C(b = [A(b = 3.0), A(b = 5.0), A(b = 3.0), null, null])
        c.duplicate();
        System.out.println(c.toString()); // C(b = [A(b = 3.0), A(b = 5.0), A(b = 3.0), A(b = 1.5), null])

    }

}
```

This does what I expected it to do, which is add another item to the array with half the `b` if two of the elements have the same returned float from `A.getB()`. However, I was trying to implement this using the fancy Java 8 stream methods and lambda functions, like so:

```
Arrays.stream(d).anyMatch(cur -> {
    if (cur == null) return false;
    Arrays.stream(d).anyMatch(nxt -> {
        if (nxt == null) return false;
        System.out.println("Checking " + cur.getB() + " with " + nxt.getB());
        return false;
    });
    return false;
});
```

And this outputted:

`Checking 3.0 with 3.0
Checking 3.0 with 5.0
Checking 3.0 with 3.0
Checking 5.0 with 3.0
Checking 5.0 with 5.0
Checking 5.0 with 3.0
Checking 3.0 with 3.0
Checking 3.0 with 5.0
Checking 3.0 with 3.0`

As you can see this follows the O(n²) algorithm which is not what I'm going for. In my original code I was "skipping" elements that I already checked by using the indexes from the outer nested for loop. So my question is, if there is a way to somehow implement this in the nested `<Stream>.anyMatch(...)` that I attempted. Or is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: are you trying to replicate the `duplicate` method but with streams API? with the same time complexity or better?

Comment: @Aomine `duplicate` was just a name I randomly thought of for the method, so no.

Comment: not talking about the method name, I am asking is the logic for the duplicate method what you're trying to replicate? or are you simply trying to improve upon the code snippet `Arrays.stream(d).anyMatch(cur -> {.........`?

Comment: @Aomine Ah okay, sorry I misunderstood. So, yes that is correct, I am trying to replicate the logic in the `duplicate` method on the last code snippet

Comment: my first question or the second.. ?

Comment: Edited my prior comment to answer this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replicate the `duplicate` method using the Stream API as follows:

```
Stream<A> result = 
       IntStream.range(0, d.length)
                .filter(cur -> d[cur] != null)
                .flatMap(cur -> IntStream.range(cur + 1, d.length)
                        .filter(nxt -> d[nxt] != null)
                        .filter(nxt -> d[cur].getB() == d[nxt].getB())
                        .map(i -> cur))
                .mapToObj(cur -> new A(d[cur].getB() * 0.5f));

d = Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(d), result)
          .toArray(A[]::new);
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please briefly explain what the purpose of `IntStream.range(cur + 1, d.length)` is please?

Comment: it simply generates an `IntStream` of numbers from `cur+1` inclusive to `d.length` exclusive i.e. just like in your code `for (int nxt = cur + 1; nxt < d.length; nxt++) {...}` @newbie